# Creating a child process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

c++ on windows
I have created a child process of cmd.exe but it gets stuck when i'm reading my pipes

```
HANDLE parent = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
char buffer[BUFSIZE];
DWORD read, written;
BOOL b = true;

for(;;)
{
    b = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, buffer, BUFSIZE, &read, NULL);
    if(! b || read == 0) break;

    b = WriteFile(parent, buffer, read, &written, NULL);
    if(! b) break;
}
```

it prints the output from cmd.exe in my console but it hangs in this loop.
i just need to figure out why it wont break the loop

Comment: Did you check what b and read evaluated to after you've read everything (while it's infinitely looping)? Do a little debugging and you'll find your answer.

Comment: Add more relevant tags, too, to draw the attention of subject matter pros. This isn't a strictly C++ question (all this looks like straight C anyway) -- more of a Windows API question.

Comment: it just hangs on ReadFile when the pipe is empty

Comment: Q: it just hangs on ReadFile when the pipe is empty   A: It's called "blocking I/O" ;)  There's a difference between "No input" and "end of input".  And between "synchronous" and "asynchronous" I/O.  You've got a "synchronous" read, apparently waiting for input that may never arrive.  Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: how would i go about reading the pipe until the pipe has no more data to be read?

Answer (score 1):

Your code as written should exit when the write end of the pipe is closed, which happens when the last handle to it is closed.  If the child process exits, its handle to the write end of the pipe will be closed automatically.

You haven't shown enough of your code for me to be certain, but the most likely cause is that you haven't closed *your* handle to the write end of the pipe.  If you close the handle after launching the subprocess, your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is infinite because b is always true because ReadFile and WriteFile are always successful in your case and read will never be 0.

Comment: Have a look at the [SetCommTimeouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: @Keith: SetCommTimeouts, according to the docs, is for serial ports, not for pipes.